# Cannot implicitly convert type 'DateTime' to 'bool' linq query

Tags: linq

I have this LINQ query:

```
var resourcePlanningInWeek = resourcePlanning.Where(rp => rp.PlanDate >= dateFrom && rp.PlanDate <= dateTo);
var holidays = new HolidayManager().GetByPeriod(dateFrom, dateTo);
var resourcePlanningExcludedHolidays= resourcePlanningInWeek.Where(rpiw => ( holidays.Where(h => h.HolidayDate = rpiw.PlanDate).Count = 0))
```

When executed, I get following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'DateTime' to 'bool'

Somewone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to use `==` instead of `=` when you want to make a comparison. That's relevant at two places in the last line.
2. The call to `Count` is missing the parentheses.

```
var resourcePlanningExcludedHolidays = resourcePlanningInWeek
    .Where(rpiw => holidays.Where(h => h.HolidayDate == rpiw.PlanDate)
                           .Count() == 0);
```

However, there is a better way of writing this:

```
var resourcePlanningExcludedHolidays = resourcePlanningInWeek
    .Where(rpiw => !holidays.Any(h => h.HolidayDate == rpiw.PlanDate));
```

This is better, because:

1. It is shorter and more readable
2. It stops enumerating `holidays` as soon as the condition is true the first time. `Count()` always enumerates the complete list.

An even better approach would be to use a `HashSet<DateTime>`:

```
var holidays
    = new HashSet<DateTime>(new HolidayManager().GetByPeriod(dateFrom, dateTo)
                                                .Select(x => x.HolidayDate));

var resourcePlanningExcludedHolidays
    = resourcePlanningInWeek.Where(rpiw => !holidays.Contains(rpiw.PlanDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an equal symbol at:

```
h.HolidayDate = rpiw.PlanDate
```

It should be:

```
var resourcePlanningExcludedHolidays= 
      resourcePlanningInWeek.Where(rpiw => ( holidays.Where(h => h.HolidayDate == rpiw.PlanDate).Count = 0))
```